# Cell is empty but IsEmpty is not working

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I am writing an IF statement that uses the IsEmpty function to determine if True or False. 
I tried it both on a cell with a value (e.g., PRB2039) and on a blank cell to test my code, and the result is the same.

I removed formatting, and tried it on a new worksheet. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: will this help? `Evaluate("isblank(" & oRange.Address & ")")`

Answer (score 8):

I prefer using

```
If Len(Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value))=0 Then Msgbox "Empty"
```

Comment: I will try this one too. I'm a begginner. thanks, Siddharth Rout.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @PatricK you may consider using ISBLANK function instead of IsEmpty function. **ISBLANK** function Returns TRUE if the value is blank

[image]

**Using VBA**

```
Sub test()

    For i = 1 To 4
       MsgBox Evaluate("isblank(" & Cells(i, 1).Address & ")")
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try  your suggestion, Santosh. Thank you.